# Combining many sets of data with different intervals

Tags: regression, missing-data

I have a dataset to analyse which goes somewhat beyond my stats knowledge.

Rather than explain the actual data I've reworded into something equivalent (it's not actually about crime).

**What I have:**

- Dependent variable is crime data, for several different classes of crimes, for a whole bunch of different towns and cities
- Independent variable is average daily temperature over the year, so it is both continuous and available for all years for each town.
- For some towns I have data from all of the last fifty years, most have some subset of those years. For example I might have 1968-2017 for Springfield, 1985-2002 for Quahog, and 1971-1985 plus 1999-2017 for South Park. It's not random - I have data for about 40 towns per year in the 1970s and about 120 towns per year in the 2010s, and in most cases towns have either one continuous stretch of data, or several continuous stretches of data with long gaps in between. Overall there are about 200 towns.
- The towns have wildly different characteristics, so just calculating the average crime per town for each year may introduce bias. In other words, I think it’s likely that the set of towns with data in 1971 are naturally more crime-ridden than the set of towns with data in 2017.
- Over 90% of the values are zeroes (i.e. most towns have no crimes in any given year). These are real meaningful zeroes, not just years that don’t have data (which I’ve left blank).
- My hypothesis is that there is a relationship between temperature and crime overall.

**Questions**

- How do I deal with the different data intervals for different towns? My instinct would be to do a multiple linear regression for each town with temperature and year as the independent variables, and then somehow average them out proportional to how many years of data are available per town. But I don't know exactly how I would do so or if this is statistically valid. I suspect this a common issue but I don’t know what terms to google.
- Does the preponderence of zeroes mean I need to change my analysis in any way? It will certainly make it less likely that I get a useable result, but should my methods change?

Thanks!

Comment: There are methods of dealing with your data, but none are easy for someone with little experience.  You are looking for something in the Poisson family of regressions, but I have another concern that you haven't included.  If you look at crime in a predator-prey model, then your logic doesn't follow.  Crime should only be greater in warmer areas if corresponding police are not hired.  That would imply temperature impacts city budgets or city design with higher crime a consequence of temperature based design.  A better test may be within cities.  Is there more crime in the summer in Boston?

Comment: Even if there is more crime in the summer, is it temperature based or event based?  In three feet of snow, is it more difficult to mug someone or escape on foot?  Just suggesting you look at the literature on the topic.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Poisson regressions. Your Boston example is pretty much exactly what I want to do. Unfortunately, I don't have enough data for Boston to actually come to any real conclusions. What I do have is data for Boston, New York, Chicago, Detroit, Philadelphia and 50 other cities, and would like to combine them for more statistical power. The question is how to combine them when different cities have data for different years.

To be clear, the data I have isn't actually about crime, just an example as my actual data is hard to explain. Don't get caught up in those details.